# Is there a WHATWG's `fullscreen` alternative?

Tags: html, video, fullscreen

As commented by [`developer.mozilla.org/docs` about Fullscreen API Browse compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Browser_compatibility), the `requestFullscreen()` and other methods are **deprecated** (say also "Not for use in new websites").

But is not easy to obtain full-screen video in one-click, even with your hosted video and using `iframe`... There are some HTML5+Javascript alternatives?

---

PS: help also [github.com/whatwg/fullscreen](https://github.com/whatwg/fullscreen/issues/166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading MDN.

`document.fullscreen` is deprecated. [`someElement.requestFullScreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) is not.

Comment: Oops, it is a (good?) news for me: "[On 28 May 2019, the W3C announced that WHATWG would be the sole publisher of the HTML and DOM standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Transition_of_HTML_Publication_to_WHATWG)"! I was looking for a W3C standard or "perspectives to `requestFullscreen` be a W3C standard"... Now I see that not need it, the only is WHATWG standard... **Is it?**